# How to only build the client module of evosuite

Tags: java, maven, evosuite

I'm trying to run the tests of Evosuite's client module, but when I try to compile the module alone maven is not able to find a dependency (evosuite-runtime) which is on the same repository and is correctly build when I compile the complete repository.

Taking a look at the POM for the client module, the dependency version is written as **${project.version}** I'm assuming is not finding it to compile. This is shown:

> [WARNING] Failed to execute goal on project evosuite-client: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.evosuite:evosuite-client:jar:1.0.7-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.evosuite:evosuite-runtime:jar:1.0.7-SNAPSHOT
>
> ...
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project evosuite-client: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.evosuite:evosuite-client:jar:1.0.7-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.evosuite:evosuite-runtime:jar:1.0.7-SNAPSHOT

When changing the version to **1.0.6** it works fine as that version is available on the [online maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.evosuite/evosuite-standalone-runtime/1.0.6), but the **1.0.7** version should be locally compiled on the fly.

Here's the client's module pom section

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.evosuite</groupId>
    <artifactId>evosuite-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And the main project pom's module section

```
<modules>
    <module>master</module>
    <module>client</module>
    <module>runtime</module>
    <module>plugins</module>
    <module>standalone_runtime</module>
    <module>shaded</module>
    <module>generated</module>
</modules>
```

Has anyone had a similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that the runtime package needed to be installed locally in order to be used to compile the client. Just run from the root module

```
mvn install
```

and that should be it.